# D3.js - Animation breaking after some time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to use this Voronoi diagram (http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning/1734663)  and what I wanted to do is adding a random movement for each node to have a constant impression of motion on the diagram.

To do this, I added this bit of code to change to position of random node at a random moment:

```
setInterval(function(){
vertices.forEach(function(d, i) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.05) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        angle = radius * (i+10);
        vertices[i].x = vertices[i].x * (1 + Math.random() / 20 * randomZ());
        vertices[i].y = vertices[i].y * (1 + Math.random() / 20 * randomZ());
      }, Math.random() * 1000);   
    }   
});

}, 1000);

function randomZ() {
  return (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : -1;
};
```

The code works fine however after a few second, the screen freezes and nothing moves anymore (at least on chrome). I am guessing I am doing to many computations at the same time.

Is there any way to fix this?

Here is the JSFiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/7krkh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is that you're using the force layout's `tick` event to update the display -- your loop only modifies the data. The force layout will cool down after a while and stop, even if you don't call `force.stop()` explicitly. No further `tick` events will be generated after that. This means that in your case, although the underlying data continues to be changed, no further updates of the display happen.

The easy fix is to simply start the force layout again at each iteration of the loop (or `setInterval` rather) that changes the data:

```
setInterval(function(){
  // ...
  force.start();
}, 1000);
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7krkh/3/).